# Correct passive voice version of "Do not disturb me"

Tags: passive-voice, imperative-sentences

This multiple-choice question appeared in an exam:

> Change the voice active /passive: **Do not disturb me.**

Options:
A. **Let me not be disturbed.**
B. **Let I not be disturbed.**
C. **Let disturb me not.**
D. **Let not disturb me.**

Some are saying the answer should be A, while some are saying the answer should be B. I know C and D can never be the answer to this. I think A is correct.

Can someone give an answer with explanation?

Comment: @sumelic on your request I've added two more options however they can never be answer to this.

Comment: @user109256 I've just inserted the missing 'b' in option A.

Comment: Meanwhile... May I say the need to passivize "do not disturb" seems like a complete and utter waste of time, and a pointless exercise. The answers sound stuffy and ridiculously antiquated. No Englishman or American speaks like this today. I'm not blaming the OP but the exam format and whoever compiled it.

Comment: Come to think of it, there is a slightly more idiomatic but just as polite equivalent *I wish not to be disturbed* but it still sounds fairly old fashioned.

Comment: We can pick the right answer because three of the alternatives are ungrammatical, but I'm reluctant to actually say that the remaining choice is the result of passivizing the original.

Comment: Other not-terrible options: "I am not to be disturbed" and "I must not be disturbed."  (Substitute "should" or "shall" for "must" if that floats your boat.)

Comment: Let's change it to **I said, "Do not disturb me!"** then the passive voice is: I said that I should/must not be disturbed.

Comment: @snailplane then what according to you should be the correct passive voice of this sentence.

Comment: @user109256 There isn't one.

Answer (score 5):

The process of elimination leaves me with answer A.

***Do not disturb me*** in the passive voice becomes ***Let me not be disturbed***. Here's why.

When imperative sentences are changed to the passive form, they generally follow this rule:

> Let + object + be + past participle

*I* is a subject pronoun. It cannot be used as an object. *Me*, on the other hand, is an object pronoun. Therefore, it makes sense only to use *me* after *let* and not *I*.

For more information, you could refer to [this](http://www.englishgrammar.org/changing-imperative-sentences-passive/).

Comment: I agree with you 100% but I think "Let me not be disturbed" sounds super archaic. I would sooner say "Don't let me be disturbed".

Answer (score 1):

The usage of **let** in this context sounds unusual. A more natural expression would be use **be** as an imperative (in this sentence, it appears as **am**):

> I am not to be disturbed.

According to NGram, the expression [not to be disturbed](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=not%20to%20be%20disturbed&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnot%20to%20be%20disturbed%3B%2Cc0) is quite widely used.

If somebody is already bothering you and you want them to stop, there is also a much more idiomatic expression:

> Let me be.

Answer (score 0):

So the safe answer will be ," you are asked /requested not to disturb me "  ? If we can speak ,you are ordered not to leave this place , so also it is better to say like ,you are ordered not to disturb me .

Comment: The OP asks which variant is correct and why, not how to interpret the sentence.

Answer (score -1):

The correct answer is

Let am I not be disturbed.

As the sentence is of simple present

The first line will go 
1.I am disturbed.
I am not disturbe.
Am I disturbed?
Am I not disturbed?
Using let..
Let am I not be disturbed.